# Can I load balance to two or more node.js servers in the same GCE VM instance using Google Load Balancer?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Using more than one node.js in a single instance is a popular node.js pattern due to its "single thread" nature so that's my challenge, to balance requests to more than one node.js on a single VM with different ports.(edited)

As far as I understood, we can only create one `backend services` per individual `instance group`, so it would be necessary to create another load balancer `(LB)` to redirect traffic to the same `instance group`/different port.

Is this correct? Will creating another `LB` to the same vm instance negatively impact `LB` policies? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

The layer 7 load balancer can only use instance groups as backends - not multiple servers on the same instance.  While co-locating multiple node servers on an instance works, there's no real value in doing that (in my opinion) in a cloud environment.  If you're interested in optimally using infrastructure, App Engine might be the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PM2 library and use the cluster mode.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

```
pm2 start app.js -i 4
```

The example above launch 4 node instances on the same server and load balance requests

Comment: I think this will only work on a single instance. My case is more than one node per instance, more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into details, I found that you can load balance to any number of nodes in the same VM instance as long as you add the ports you will balance in the instance groups `Port name mapping (Optional)`

So you can have more than one VM instance each one with more than one active `node.js`.